# Node formidable form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) -> files return to {} when uploading file size over than 1Gb

Tags: formidable

I'm using [Node formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable) to upload files in my nodejs project(express + formidable), it works smoothly when uploading small file.

```
form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
    console.log(files);
}
```

I got the files object which frontend fired from form.parse callback function. 
But it will return to empty object when the incoming file is too big(over than 1Gb through my test).

I looked all over with no luck. It will be great if someone could shine some light on this issue.

Comment: I've set form.maxFieldsSize property. 
files will return to empty object immediately even it has not finished uploading during uploading the big file.

Answer (score 0):

I found I set `form.maxFieldsSize` rather than `form.maxFileSize` in express backend. 
This issue is gone after setting maxFileSize property.